# Is there an utility which can profile and report on the activity of a single process?

Tags: utilities, activity-monitor

Activity monitor can report on a single processes's disk and cpu usage at a single point in time.

The "Sample Process" feature is good for debugging, but doesn't provide easily digestible information.

Apps like iStat are just pretty layers on top of activity monitor.

**Is there an app for OSX which will sample a Processes's resource use over time and then provide a report with nice graphs?**

**Something like [DaisyDisk](http://daisydiskapp.com/) but for cpu and disk usage for a single process over time?**

Answer (score 1):

I think [BigTop](http://osx.iusethis.com/app/bigtop) is what you're looking for. It comes with the Developer Tools (which are on the install disc that came with your Mac)

Comment: +1 thanks daviesgeek, i'll check it out to see if it does what i need

Comment: hey daviesgeek..... bigtop doesn't seem to work with Lion..? is that correct? cheers

Comment: @andy I actually don't know. I don't have Lion yet. And from the compatibility issues I have been hearing about, it may be awhile before I upgrade...